# How to access to a button or an input content that was loaded (html file) with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html file that have an input and a button, I load this file in another html file with jquery. And now, I want to access the input and button to do something and I don't know how to do that.

The bottom (div) is what I load in another file.
The last code is a script to load the html file.

Can You Help ME??

```
  <div class="newsletter">
    <h6 class="headerDIV">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h6>
    <input id="newsletterInputEmail" class="input-email"type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here">
    <button id="newsletterButtonSubmit" width="100px"class="w3-button w3-round-xlarge w3-grey">Submit</button>
    <p><label id="newsletterEmailMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <p><input id="newsletterCheckbox" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"><label class="textRights">I have read and accepted the general terms and conditions*</label></p>
    <p><label id="newsletterCheckboxMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <label class="textRights2">See our <a href="politics/privacy/politica_de_privacidade_pt.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">Privacy Notice</a> for more information.</label>
  </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newsletter").load("standardSite/newsletter.html");
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: after loading the html, can you not do `$('.newsletter').find('#newsletterInputEmail')` ?
what exactly you're tying to do i.e. after accessing input and button, what should be done. If there is a particular requirement such as submit input on click of the button, please explain clearly so it is easy to understand.

Comment: Well, I want to grab the data insert in input content when the user click in the button

Comment: ok and is it confirmed that there will only be 1 newsletter? because if there are more, you cannot use id on button and label as that will not be valid.

Comment: Only one newsletter

Comment: ok, i've added an answer to fit your requirement, let me know if you have doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind events to dynamically generated elements, you need to do [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) jquery offers.

```
$('#newsletter').on('click', '#newsletterButtonSubmit', function(){
     var inputVal = $(this).parent('div').find('#newsletterInputEmail').val();
});
```

Above assumes that there will be unique id per element. If you're loading it multiple times, there will be multiple elements with the same id. In that case, you should use unique id or a class as done below:

```
$('#newsletter').on('click', '.newsletterButtonSubmit', function(){
     var inputVal = $(this).parent('div').find('.newsletterInputEmail').val();
});
```

Check this snippet:

```js
$('#newsletter').on('click', '#newsletterButtonSubmit', function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).parent('div').find('#newsletterInputEmail').val();
  console.log(inputVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newsletter">
  <div class="newsletter">
    <h6 class="headerDIV">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h6>
    <input id="newsletterInputEmail" class="input-email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here">
    <button id="newsletterButtonSubmit" width="100px" class="w3-button w3-round-xlarge w3-grey">Submit</button>
    <p><label id="newsletterEmailMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <p><input id="newsletterCheckbox" class="w3-check" type="checkbox"><label class="textRights">I have read and accepted the general terms and conditions*</label></p>
    <p><label id="newsletterCheckboxMSG" class="textFillField">This field is mandatory</label></p>
    <label class="textRights2">See our <a href="politics/privacy/politica_de_privacidade_pt.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">Privacy Notice</a> for more information.</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store the input by user and then you can use the variable wherever you want:

```
document.getElementById("buttonid").onclick =function(){
    var input = document.getElementById("boxid").value();
}
```